# Scrollbar not coming in DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grid, scrollbar, wpfdatagrid

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Version WPF.

I am new to WPF and creating the simple sample which contains the grid that binds from database but it is not showing me the scroll bar.

Before using Grid directly DataGrid show the scroll bar but after put into the Grid not showing me the scroll bar.

Here is a code please correct me anywhere I am wrong!

```
<Grid>
        <control:HeaderControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-242,0,388" Width="1360"></control:HeaderControl>
        <control:FooterControl Margin="0,75,5,-75"></control:FooterControl>
        <Label Content="Products List :"  Margin="0,82,0,30"/>
        <Grid Margin="6,1,194,199">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,108,1100,30" Name="grdProduct" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFC4B0B0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Width="120" Header="Product Name"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitName}" Width="100" Header="Unit Name"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="50" Header="Price"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

and here is the output

[image]

The coming data is so big so I need a scroll bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `ScrollViewer`

Comment: @Gopichandar Not useful. there is no change in output remains same.

Comment: Try my answer .  Let me know if you still face any issue in it.

Comment: @Gopichandar No it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure.  Are you looking for [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
   <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Margin="6,1,194,199">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,108,1100,30" Name="grdProduct" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFC4B0B0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Width="120" Header="Product Name"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitName}" Width="100" Header="Unit Name"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="50" Header="Price"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Make sure to define the `MaxHeight` for the `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Do I need to remove Grid?

Comment: That's your wise.  I'm not sure why you are having that. . If you want you can have the `Grid` inside the `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Yes it's working but my scroll bar is very far from my displayed records width wise very far how to solve this!

Comment: You have to set the `Width` for the `ScrollViewer`. .

Comment: Ya sure ,I have change the width of the scrollbar it fixed but it also change the place of datagrid. I really can't understand why it affects other controls by changing the single control! Can you give me one tutorial site or any link from where I can properly understand the WPF, please!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98332/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-gopichandar).